# Can anyone id this broken tail light? with the vehicle to the car that almost hit us

Tags: car, part-identification, tail-lights

[image]

Is it possible for someone to id this tail light section?

Comment: I don't get why you possess a broken tail light from a car that did not hit you.

Comment: Loks lije a Citroen C4.